# Find the geometric locus $z \in \mathbb C$ so that $\frac{z+2}{z(z+1)}\in \mathbb R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, contest-math

> Find the geometric locus of the set of $z \in \mathbb C$ so that 
>   $$\frac{z+2}{z(z+1)}\in \mathbb R$$
>   **Source:** IME (Military Engineering Institute, Brazil, entrance exam, 1974)

**My attempt:** With the notation $z=a+bi$, the solution provided in a book is either the line $b=0$ or the circle $(a+2)^2+b^2=2$  but I could not find it, or not able to recognize this locus set from the algebraic development I did (or the solution or the statement has some mistake).

Hints and solutions are welcomed.

Answer (score 6):

A complex number $w$ is real if and only if it equals its conjugate $\bar{w}$. So you need to solve
$$
\frac{z+2}{z(z+1)}=\frac{\bar{z}+2}{\bar{z}(\bar{z}+1)}
$$
Cross multiplication gives
$$
z\bar{z}^2+z\bar{z}+2\bar{z}^2+2\bar{z}=z^2\bar{z}+z\bar{z}+2z^2+2z
$$
and we can transfer everything to the right-hand side:
$$
z\bar{z}(z-\bar{z})+2(z^2-\bar{z}^2)+2(z-\bar{z})=0
$$
This has the entire real line ($z=\bar{z}$) as a solution, points $z=0$ and $z=-1$ excluded, of course; removing this factor we find all other solutions:
$$
z\bar{z}+2(z+\bar{z})+2=0 \tag{*}
$$
Now we can substitute $z=x+yi$:
$$
x^2+y^2+4x+2=0
$$
that is,
$$
(x+2)^2+y^2=2
$$
which is a circle.

You can avoid passing to real coordinates by noticing that the equation (*) can be rewritten as $z\bar{z}+2z+2\bar{z}+4=2$, so $(z+2)(\bar{z}+2)=2$ and finally
$$
|z+2|^2=2
$$
which is clearly a circle with center at $2$ and radius $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** Multiply the fraction by 
$$
\frac{\bar z(\bar z-1)}{\bar z(\bar z-1)}\;.
$$
In this way the denominator will be real and you should only look at the numerator, splitting it into its real and imaginary part.

Answer (score 2):

A little [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html) before rationalization of the denominator will reduce calculation.

$$\dfrac{z+2}{z(z+1)}=\dfrac1{z+1}+\dfrac{2(z+1-z)}{z(z+1)}=\dfrac2z-\dfrac1{z+1}$$

Now the imaginary part of $\dfrac2z$ is $-\dfrac{2y}{x^2+y^2}$

and that of $\dfrac1{z+1}$ is $-\dfrac y{(x+1)^2+y^2}$

Finally, $\dfrac{z+2}{z(z+1)}$ will be real if $-\dfrac{2y}{x^2+y^2}=-\dfrac y{(x+1)^2+y^2}$

$\iff0=y(2x^2+2y^2+4x+2-x^2-y^2)=y\{(x+2)^2+y^2-2\}$

Answer (score 2):

Using

$$
z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{\arctan\frac yx}
$$

we have

$$
\frac{z+2}{z(z+1)} = \frac{\rho_1 e^{i\phi_1}}{\rho_2 e^{i\phi_2}\rho_3 e^{i\phi_3}}
$$

and we seek for

$$
\arctan\frac{y}{x+2}-\arctan\frac yx -\arctan\frac{y}{x+1} = 0
$$

then

$$
\tan\left(\arctan\frac{y}{x+2} -\arctan\frac{y}{x+1}\right) = \frac yx
$$

or

$$
y(y^2+x^2+4x+2) = 0
$$

NOTE

$$
\tan(a-b) = \frac{\tan a-\tan b}{1+\tan a\tan b}
$$

so

$$
\tan\left(\arctan\frac{y}{x+2} -\arctan\frac{y}{x+1}\right) = \frac{y}{y^2+x^2+3x+2}
$$

etc.

Comment: How did you get that last step?

Comment: @IlikeSerena Please. See attached note.

Comment: @bluemaster Thanks for the hint.  I have a real problem with addition (and subtraction)